# Is it possible to evaluate $\prod_{j=1}^{m}\sin(\sqrt{j}x)$

Tags: trigonometry, products

Basically wondering if it's possible to evaluate or approximate products like,

$$\prod_{j=1}^{m}\sin(\sqrt{j}x)$$
I thought that
$$\sin^{m}(\sqrt{0.5m}x)$$
may be a reasonal approximation, since it uses the average value of $j$, however I'm not at all experienced with these kinds of sums so wouldn't know where to start to see if it is reasonable

Comment: Do you mean product not sum? Replace $sin(\theta)$ with $\frac{e^{i \theta}-e^{-i \theta}}{2i}$ is probably a good start.

Comment: The best we can do is an approximation, viz.$$\exp\sum_j\ln\sin\left(x\sqrt{j}\right)\approx\exp\int_0^m\ln\sin\left(x\sqrt{s}\right)ds=\exp\int_0^m2t\ln\sin\left(xt\right)dt,$$but even then we need numerical integration. There are also issues if $x\sqrt{m}\notin(0,\,\pi)$; the above analysis neglects the possibility of sines $\le0$.

Comment: Near $0$, this is $\approx \sqrt{m!}x^m$, but for large $x$, note that the various factors have (mostly) incommensurable periods, so for example the zeroes are located a bit "chaotically"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $x$ is real, your product converges to $0$ as $m \to \infty$.  How fast it converges, however, will depend on how close $\sqrt{j} x$ gets to integer multiples of $\pi$.  This is too delicate for there to be a closed-form formula.
If $(x/\pi)^2$ is rational, say $a/b$, then
your product will be $0$ for $m \ge ab$.